How can I change the form of coordinates of a point from the form (1, 2, 3) to the form (1; 2; 3)?
I have this picture.

I tried
     \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    Let  $ABC$ be a triangle with  $A(1,2,3)$, $B(4,5,9)$, $(7,8,6)$. Coordinates of centroid of the given triangle is  $(4,5,6)$.
        \end{document}

I want to write coordinates of points in the form $(a; b; c)$.

I tried
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\myway(#1,#2,#3){(#1;\,#2;\,#3)}
\begin{document}
    Let  $ABC$ be a triangle with  $A(1,2,3)$, $B(4,5,9)$, $(7,8,6)$. Coordinates of centroid of the given triangle is  $\myway(4,5,6)$.
    
Let  $ABC$ be a triangle with  $A\myway(1,2,3)$, $B\myway(4,5,9)$, $\myway(7,8,6)$. Coordinates of centroid of the given triangle is  $\myway(4,5,6)$.
\end{document}

If I have 200 triangles, can I reduce macros \myway to a simpler anotherway?
I posted my problem here

If the sentence structure is sufficiently predictable then I would suggest search and replace in your editor, instead of trying to solve it with LaTeX. To keep the numbers you can use a regular expression find and replace with backreferences, something like find given triangle is $\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)$ and replace with given triangle is $(\1;\,\2;\,\3)$ (untested, you probably need to check carefully which characters need escaping in the regular expression and which dialect your editor uses for the backreferences.

Just to make sure I'm not misunderstanding: Why don't you just write $A(1; 2; 3)$ in the first place?

I use Mathematica to create a list of triangles, e.g. 100, 200 triangles. Mathematica is ouput {1,2,3}.

It's easy enough to write a macro converting that format into what you want, but only if we know precisely what you have. What do you get from Mathematica? Text or just the coordinates? Does it insert macro names? (If so, why can't it change the coordinate format?) Does it output braces or parentheses? It's all a bit unclear. Ideally, make an MWE that fits your actual problem (i.e. it resembles your actual Mathematica output).

Please see here

Not serious, but in the very unlikely edge case of no mathmode-material in the document other than the triples containing comma and the replacement of comma by semicolon only being needed in mathmode you can probably define active comma to expand to semicolon and give comma the mathcode "8000 (which means 8000(hex)=215(dec)=32768(dec)):
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Usually ~ is active, so...
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\,\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{;\,}\mathcode`\,="8000 %
\begin{document}
Let  $ABC$ be a triangle with  $A(1,2,3)$, $B(4,5,9)$, $(7,8,6)$. Coordinates of centroid of the given triangle is  $(4,5,6)$.
\end{document}


It cannot be emphasized strong enough that this approach is rather an "academical thing" not suitable in most real-life use-cases.
Therefore a comment of the user  Marijn is quoted:

Note, as Ulrich explains clearly (but it cannot hurt to emphasize again), that this is most likely a bad idea with unwanted side effects, and it would be better to either modify the export format from Mathematica or to post-process the output separately before running LaTeX.

The author of the initial release of this answer, Ulrich Diez, is of the opinion that this answer should not be upvoted too often as upvotes might seduce people unskilled in matters of TeX and LaTeX into considering usage in real life scenarios.

Note, as Ulrich explains clearly (but it cannot hurt to emphasize again), that this is most likely a bad idea with unwanted side effects, and it would be better to either modify the export format from Mathematica or to post-process the output separately before running LaTeX.

@Marijn As your comment is true I took the liberty to quote it within the answer itself. ;-)
